# C++ binary tree with min heap

Tags: c++, binary, heap, min

I am trying to make a min heap in a tree, however I am new in here and I have  already two weeks now going back and forward with the pointers and addresses,

so I'm making a structure like this:

```
struct node{
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};
```

and then a insert function like this:

```
void Insert(int dataii){
    node* new_node = new node();
    new_node->data = dataii;
    new_node->left = new_node->right = NULL;
}
```

ok, now is when my problems start, how to connect the nodes to make them a tree.

I am thinking to use a array to store the numbers of new_nodes in the array[0] and then the array[1] and so on linking them with the valor of new_node->data and address.

But I dont seem to find a working code to make this work. my goal is to make a binary tree with a min heap, but I am not being able to do the tree yet.

Once that each parent will have two childrens maximum, and always when inserting they are going from the left to the right.

If anyone could give me a good idea how to go forward, thanks.
Tiago

Comment: Normally, a function like `Insert` would need to specify _where_ the node is being inserted.  As a parameter or by virtue of being a member function.  Much like with English, you usually can't insert something without specifying _where_.

Comment: Are you trying this in c or c++?  If in c, then have the `Insert` func take in the node you want to insert to, if in c++, try making `node` a class.

Comment: It's actually easier to store heaps as linear arrays, instead of actual binary trees with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node{
public:
    int data;
    Node *left, *right;

    Node(int data);
    ~Node();
    int count();
    void insert(Node *n);
    void print(const int indent, const char* note);
};

Node::Node(int data) {
   this->data = data;
   this->left = this->right = NULL;
}

Node::~Node(){
    if (this->left != NULL) delete this->left;
    if (this->right != NULL) delete this->right;
}

int Node::count() {
    int r = 1;
    if (this->left != NULL) r += this->left->count();
    if (this->right != NULL) r += this->right->count();
    return r;
}

void Node::insert(Node* n){
    if (this->left == NULL) this->left = n;
    else if (this->right == NULL) this->right = n;
    else if (this->left->count() > this->right->count()) this->right->insert(n);
    else this->left->insert(n);
}

void Node::print(const int indent=0, const char *note="") {
    for(int i = 0; i < indent; i++) cout << " ";
    cout << this->data << " " << note << endl;
    if (this->left != NULL) this->left->print(indent+1, "(l)");
    if (this->right != NULL) this->right->print(indent+1, "(r)");
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    Node *root = new Node(0);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) root->insert(new Node(i));
    root->print();
    delete root;
    return 0;
}
```

[See full project with implemented min/max heaps](https://github.com/popmedic/cpp-heaps)